# A question about compactness

Tags: compactness

There is the question: deduce that $Y$ is a compact subset of $(X,d)$ iff the metric space $(Y,d)$ is compact. (Given that $Y$is a subset of $X$).

How to show it? (I cannot find anything to show though...)

Comment: This is a straightforward application of the the subspace topology. What party of the proof are your stuck on?

Comment: There is a difference between a compact subset of a metric space, and a compact metric space. This is about showing that the difference is small enough that they deserve to use the same word.

Comment: Something to help you along...is every subset of a compact metric space $(X,d)$ also compact? What could go wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be sure you are using a definition of compactness that does not depend on the ambient space, such as the traditional one that any open cover admits a finite subcover.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that the context is this one: we say that $Y(\subset X)$ is compact if, for every family $(A_\lambda)_{\lambda\in\Lambda}$ such that $Y\subset\bigcup_{\lambda\in\Lambda}$, there is a finite subset $F$ of $\Lambda$ such that $Y\subset\bigcup_{\lambda\in F}$. If so, saying that $(Y,d)$ is a compact space and saying that $Y$ is a compct subset of $X$ are two different things. It's not hard to prove that they are equivalent.

Comment: So does it mean that I need to show sequential compactness is equivalent to compactness?

Comment: @user556970 No. I made no reference to sequences.

Comment: The definition that you mentioned above is the compactness of a subset, right?

Comment: What is the definition of compactness of a metric space then?

Comment: @user556970 Yes, it is..

Comment: @user556970 Every open cover haas a finite subcover.

Comment: But I thought that the definition above were the same as "every open cover has a finite subcover"... Could you write the methematical expressions for "every open cover has a finite subcover"? Thank you!

Comment: @user556970 For every family of open subsets of $Y$ whose union is $Y$, there is a finite subfamily whose union is still $Y$.

Comment: Does it mean that, the difference between compactness of a subset and that of a metric space: cpct of a subset only needs ⊂ but cpct of a metric space needs = ? (Is this the difference betweem two definitions?)